# Is it possible to allow saved passwords for remote desktop in a domain environment?

Tags: windows, domain, remote-desktop, login

I have checked the "remember password" and every single time, even if it connects correctly after I type a password and check the box, it does not allow subsequent logins using the stored password, saying that it is invalid - is it being saved improperly somehow? is it being disabled by some obscure setting somewhere? (which would be very counter-intuitive, seeing as how the check box is available).

I have tried both with domain and non-domain (local) admin accounts, and am using the FQDN for the server.

edit: as a troubleshooting step, where would one go to find the (hopefully hashed) password?

Comment: [This](http://superuser.com/a/606416/224330) might be helpful if you're getting the [same error](http://i.imgur.com/M8BKMum.png) that I see.

Comment: @NathanC D'oh - that was it, thanks! as a side-note, is there any way to configure it at the domain level instead of on each individual client?

Comment: I don't know...I tried the same steps but they didn't work, so I guess your mileage may vary. :P

Comment: @NathanC - I followed the steps and managed to get it to work on 1/3 computers.. I am now more confused than before

Comment: Related: [Why won't RDP accept my stored credentials, and makes me manually enter it every time?](https://serverfault.com/q/767159/300053)

Answer (score 0):

Passwords are stored in the Password safe in your account:

```
Start / run / control keymgr.dll
```

From there you can see all stored password from Windows.