# Why won't RDP accept my stored credentials, and makes me manually enter it every time?

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp, windows-authentication, credentials

Trying to log in to an Amazon EC2 instance (running Windows Server 2012 R2) via RDP.  It works, and I can connect, but having saved the credentials that worked, they never seem to be accepted on subsequent logins, always rejecting them and requiring me to reenter the password part manually.

[image: Screenshot of login prompt dialog]

Nothing about *why* it didn't work, just that it didn't — "Your credentials did not work" and "The logon attempt failed".  Then I type in the same password as always and it works.

I can see that the credentials are in fact saved in the Credential Manager, and the right name is always filled in trying to log on.  I can also see it trying the saved credentials for a split second before being presented with this dialog.

After googling around for an answer, I've tried several things, including using an IP address vs. a FQDN, doing that thing with the Group Policy editor ("Allow Delegating Saved Credentials with NTLM-only Server Authentication"), and checking the Group Policy on the remote side for anything unusual-looking.  No dice.

**How do I get it to accept the credentials it saved and not prompt me each time?**

Answer (score 8):

> To be able to use saved credentials in this situation you need to do
>   the following:
>
> - Open Group Policy Editor via cmd -> gpedit.msc
> - Navigate to Local Computer Policy\Computer    Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Credentials Delegation\
> - Open Setting Allow Delegating Saved Credentials with NTLM-only Server    Authentication, set it to Enabled click on button Show...
>     and in Show    Contents window add Value TERMSRV/* Close all windows
>     by pressing OK.
> - Run cmd and enter gpupdate command to update your policy.
>
> Now you should be able to use your saved credentials.

Source: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/remote-desktop-connection-not-using-saved/13a17d84-b008-4767-95fb-b891e9e6bc66?auth=1

or try the solution from link below:
https://superuser.com/questions/604483/windows-7-remote-desktop-connection-save-credentials-not-working

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

On Windows 10:

In Credential Manager, within the Windows Credentials section, try deleting the credentials from the Windows Credentials sub-section and instead re-creating them in the Generic Credentials section.

Comment: connection to win server 2019 repaired once and forever, thx!

Comment: thank you so much. tried so many different things and this fixed it. Seems to be a Windows 10 bug though.